# Worklight 6.1 - How to set x-forwarded Ip address in request header at adapter level

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using worklight 6.1 and facing some issue for getting x-forwarded ip address at adapter level which we want while request. So right now i am sending client ip address from client side on adapter like this given below

```
WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
                    console.log(networkInfo.ipAddress); 
                    ipadd = networkInfo.ipAddress;
                    reqParams["fldAppipAddress"] = networkInfo.ipAddress;
                });
                var invocationData = {
                        adapter : "Login",
                        procedure : "Login",
                        parameters : [id,reqParams,ipadd],
                        compressResponse : true
                };
```

and adapter side I am setting header like this

```
var request={
             method:'POST',
             returnedContentType:'xml',
             path:serverPathIs,
             headers:{"User-Agent":"","App-Version":"1.6","X-Forwarded-For":Ipaddress},
             cookies: {"JSESSIONID":cookiestr},
             parameters:jsonstr,
     };
```

Even after doing this i am not getting x-forwarded ip , please suggest the proper way.

How to set `x-forwarded-for` in header of http request.

@ Anton

```
function GetAPICal(fldjsessionid,jsonstr,pass,uid,Ipaddress){
  WL.Logger.error(jsonstr);
  WL.Logger.info(jsonstr);
    //newjson={"fldPassword":enc(pass)};

    var output = {};
    output = jsonConcat(jsonstr, newjson);
     serverPathIs=getServletPathInfo();
     if(fldjsessionid){
         cookieSplit = fldjsessionid.split('!');
        cookiestr = cookieSplit[0]+"!"+cookieSplit[1];
     }
     else{
         cookiestr="123";
     }
     var request={
             method:'POST',
             returnedContentType:'xml',
             path:serverPathIs,
             headers:{"User-Agent":"","App-Version":"1.6","X-Forwarded-For":Ipaddress},
             cookies: {"JSESSIONID":cookiestr},
             parameters:output,
     };

     var req = WL.Server.getClientRequest();




     var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(request);


     return response;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Take x-forwarded-for header from client->adapter request and use it in adapter->backend request?

Comment: Whatever request we are making to backend from adapter, we want header x-forwarded ip over there thats it.

Comment: What do you want as a value of that header?

Comment: headers:{X-Forwarded-For":Ipaddress}   and this Ipaddress i am sending from client so i want this as in request.

Comment: Can you paste full Login function code? Looks like you're sending ipaddress twice from client and I don't see any reason for that

Comment: It is already there in my post ipadd  variable m passing as a parameter to adapter and settting this as a request header in x-forwarded for

Comment: No it is not. Can you add your adapter Login function, currently there's only a snippet out of it.

Comment: Please check adapter process

Comment: You've added GetAPICal function and your client invokes Login function. It is impossible to debug the flow without seeing all pieces of a puzzle. Can you add all the relevant functions? In general - your code looks correct, it should add X-Forwarded-For header to the adapter->backend request. Can you elaborate what exactly the problem is? Header not being added? Wrong header value?